# i have Webgrid in razor engine when i perform grid function grid is postbacking to first page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, gridview, razor, webgrid

I have webgrid in Razor engine. When I perform edit function, grid is coming back to grid pageone, how can I restrict the grid to stay back in same page of grid when we perform any grid functionality?

Comment: can you describe your edit function ?

Answer (score 0):

public class PeopleListController : Controller
    {
        //sample data source
        public List Persons 
        { 
            get {
                return new List { 
                    new Person {ID=1, Birthday=DateTime.Now, Name="John"},
                    new Person {ID=2, Birthday=DateTime.Now, Name="Paul"},
                    new Person {ID=3, Birthday=DateTime.Now, Name="Jane"},
                    new Person {ID=4, Birthday=DateTime.Now, Name="Trisha"},
                    new Person {ID=5, Birthday=DateTime.Now, Name="Kevin"},
                    new Person {ID=6, Birthday=DateTime.Now, Name="Janice"},
                    new Person {ID=7, Birthday=DateTime.Now, Name="Dennis"},
                    new Person {ID=8, Birthday=DateTime.Now, Name="Jack"},
                    new Person {ID=9, Birthday=DateTime.Now, Name="Trevor"},
                    new Person {ID=10, Birthday=DateTime.Now, Name="Michael"},
                    new Person {ID=11, Birthday=DateTime.Now, Name="Sean"},
                    new Person {ID=12, Birthday=DateTime.Now, Name="Emerson"},
                    new Person {ID=13, Birthday=DateTime.Now, Name="Jay"},
                    new Person {ID=14, Birthday=DateTime.Now, Name="Henry"},
                    new Person {ID=15, Birthday=DateTime.Now, Name="Luke"}
                };
            }
        }

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //get grid parameters from URL/POST (if any)
        var gridParameters = GridParameters.GetGridParameters();

        //get data
        var data = GetDataUsingLINQ(gridParameters.Sort,            //order by column
                                    gridParameters.SortDirection,   //order by direction
                                    gridParameters.Page ?? 1,       //returned page
                                    5);                             //displayed rows per page

        //set record count for use in view
        ViewBag.GridRecordCount = Persons.Count;

        return View(data);
    }

    //get data from datasource using LINQ (sample data access layer)
    private IEnumerable<Person> GetDataUsingLINQ(string sort, string sortDir, int page, int numRows)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sort))
            return Persons.AsQueryable().OrderBy(sort + " " + sortDir).Skip((page - 1) * numRows).Take(numRows).ToList();
        else
            return Persons.AsQueryable().Skip((page - 1) * numRows).Take(numRows).ToList();
    }

    //get data from datasource using SPROC (sample data access layer)
    private IEnumerable<Person> GetDataUsingSPROC(string sort, string sortDir, int? page, int numRows)
    {
        //note: I did not use EF nor LINQ to SQL in the example below as I do 
        //      not know any clean/elegant way of calling stored using those two

        //note: server side paging and sorting SP implementation is not included, there are lots of articles on the web that discuss about it.
        //      You can google "sql server side paging sorting"

        var sqlCon = new SqlConnection("<insert your connection string here>");
        sqlCon.Open();

        var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "<insert your SP name here>"; 
        sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon;

        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sort", sort);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SortDirection", sortDir);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Page", page);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumRows", numRows);

        var list = new List<Person>();
        using(SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var p = new Person();
                p.ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]);
                p.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                p.Birthday = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Birthday"]);
                list.Add(p);
            }
        }

        sqlCon.Close();

        return list;
    }
```

}